# c# how to assign Console.WriteLine to variable

Tags: c#

I Would like to shorten typing Console.WriteLine and assign it to var for example:
var write = Console.WriteLine();
and execute it like
write("My name is.."); >>>output>> My name is...

Comment: Why? The next person who is going to read your code has to lookup what 'write' does. It's just an useless wrapper. Focus on readability and not on code/line length. You will thank yourself later.

Comment: Are you writing this programme for yourself?

Comment: Three upvotes for a (poorly formatted) question that nobody in their right mind should attempt?

Comment: @RvdK I 'm usually using console.writeline to check if function run properly so it is much more simpler to use shorter version

Comment: @MTo, so would naming a class `Z`, but that doesn't mean you should do it.  Both make the code harder to reason about in the future.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assigning a method to a variable is done though the use of a delegate:

```
Action<string> write = Console.WriteLine;
write("Hello World!");
```

Of course the delegate won't be able to represent every single overload of `Console.WriteLine` (and it has 18 of them).  It can only represent one of the overloads (but it can represent any one of those 18).

Comment: You can use the `params` overload and you are done, like I did here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26782954/c-sharp-how-to-assign-console-writeline-to-variable/26783180#26783180

Comment: @Andrew Yes, I said as much in the answer.

Comment: Is it possible to use `Action<>` as a delegate for the `(string format, params object[] arg)` overload? I tried for a minute but couldn't do it.

Comment: @Andrew No, it is not possible to use `Action` for a `params` parameter.

Answer (score 5):

Although doing it simply to shorten your code is a questionable idea, here is what you can do: define a delegate for the `Write` method, like this

```
delegate void WriteDelegate(string msg, params object[] args);
```

Define a variable of type `WriteDelegate`, and assign `Console.Write` to it:

```
private static readonly WriteDelegate w = Console.Write;
```

Now you can use `w` to call `Console.Write`, with or without parameters:

```
w("Hello");
w(", {0}", "world!");
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/VBEfGe)

Comment: Damn 3 Seconds faster! Gj :P

Comment: But his is actually better. :)

@dasblinkenlight, you beat me for seconds. :P
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26782954/c-sharp-how-to-assign-console-writeline-to-variable/26783180#26783180

Comment: @Andrew Yup, that's why I deleted my answer. But well - OP never mentioned optional arguments, so I didn't include them :) Its a nice answer tho!

Answer (score 4):

You can have a static method `Write` like:

```
public static void Write(string value)
{
    Console.WriteLine("My name is.." + value);
}
```

and then you can call it like:

```
Write("SomeName");
```

**With C# 6.0** you have an option to use [static import](http://davefancher.com/2014/08/07/c-6-0-using-static/): You can do:

```
using static System.Console;
```

and then in your method you can do:

```
WriteLine("My name is...");
```

EDIT: Since the release of Visual Studio 2015 CTP, in January 2015, static import feature requires explicit mention of static keyword like:

```
using static System.Console;
```

Comment: @DeeMac, thanks for pointing that out. Edit: thanks again :) just copied the code from question :)

Comment: Sorted. +1 for static import, I didn't know about that.

Comment: I know, but it's nice to get a heads up on stuff that'll be available soon. http://davefancher.com/2014/08/14/c-6-0-null-propagation-operator/ < this is looking like it could be a favourite too.

Answer (score 2):

A more flexible option is to use a `delegate`. It allows you to write both a simple string or a formatted one.

```
class Program
{
    delegate void writeDelegate(string format, params object[] arg);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        writeDelegate write = Console.WriteLine;

        write("Simple text.");
        write("Formatted {0}: {1}", "text", 10);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Anyway, as others pointed out, this is a bit awkward; I wouldn't do this. You are adding the risk of confusing the developer who reads your code, who may end up being your future self.

Answer (score 1):

You could always define your own method and defer to the Console static instance.  However, what I think you're really after won't be ready until c# 6.0 and is a feature named "Static Using Statmenets", you can read more about it here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn683793.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
void write(string message)
{
    Console.WriteLine(message);
}
```

Usage:

```
write("log this");
```

NOTE: I'd re-think the case and naming convention of your method. It should really be `Write`.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is an Action. Use it like this:

```
Action<string> write = Console.WriteLine;
write("Your message here");
```

This will do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to **[@dasblinkenlight answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26783174/618220)**. Modifying the delegate signature to

```
delegate void WriteDelegate(string msg = "", params object[] args);
```

will now let you now call with 0 parameters as well.

```
private static readonly WriteDelegate w = Console.Write;
w("Hello");
w(", {0}", "world!");
w(); // Calling with no parameter
```

Answer (score 0):

This is completely and utterly useless, but if you want to do it anyways, you can define a **delegate** like this:

`delegate void ProcessString(string input);`.

Now,  create a `ProcessString` variable and pass it the `Console.WriteLine` callable:

`ProcessString write = new ProcessString(Console.WriteLine);`.

Then you can just call `write` and it will behave completely like `Console.WriteLine`.